# Getting rid of default red border for required fields

Tags: html, angularjs, internet-explorer

I have some required fields in the form. For required fields I want 1px red border for highlighting form fields after form submit. Chrome is doing that perfectly. IE is giving troubles with default and broad borders. How to get rid of those?

HTML source code:

```
<div class="tableRow">
    <div class="tableCell fieldCaption borderBottom normalFontWeight">{{'_PHONE_'|i18n}}<span class="mandetory">*</span></div>
    <div class="tableCell fieldValue borderBottom">
        <input type="text" name="phoneValueInput" ng-class="{submitted:createCallBackForm.phoneValueInput.$invalid}" ng-model="taskDto.ContactPhoneNumber" placeholder="{{'_PHONE_NUMBER_'|i18n}}" required  validation-message="{{'_MSG_EMPTY_PHONE_NUMBER_'|i18n}}"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input.submitted.ng-invalid {
    border: red 1px solid;
}
```

Code served to IE 11:

```
<div class="tableRow">
    <div class="tableCell fieldCaption borderBottom normalFontWeight ng-binding">Telefoon<span class="mandetory">*</span></div>
    <div class="tableCell fieldValue borderBottom">
        <input name="phoneValueInput" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-dirty" style="margin-left: 10px;" required="" type="text" placeholder="Telefoonnummer" ng-model="taskDto.ContactPhoneNumber" ng-class="{submitted:createCallBackForm.phoneValueInput.$invalid}" validation-message="Telefoonnummer kan niet leeg zijn">
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Code served to Chrome (Version 35.0.1916.114 m):

```
<div class="tableRow">
    <div class="tableCell fieldCaption borderBottom normalFontWeight ng-binding">Phone<span class="mandetory">*</span></div>
    <div class="tableCell fieldValue borderBottom">
        <input type="text" name="phoneValueInput" ng-class="{submitted:createCallBackForm.phoneValueInput.$invalid}" ng-model="taskDto.ContactPhoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number" required="" validation-message="Phone number can not be empty" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Similar kind of scenario can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/qTV3g/

Comment: Post the html & css, please, so we can see what could be happening.

Comment: Create a fiddle/demo link

Comment: @DevPat: I will create and share the link.

Comment: as always with IE, which version of IE this issue occurs?

Comment: I think that's the source code, not the html served to the browser, so we can not verify if the class selector could be working. About the css, it seems ok, but without the other rules I can't see if it is some kind of specificity strange behaviour, etc

Comment: @miguel-svq: Do you want to see html code server to the browser?

Comment: It's for me @Ajinkya , but it's better if you just "view-source" in the browser and copy-paste it here, so others can check it too

Comment: The css selector `input.submitted.ng-invalid` does not match the `class` in the html, since it don't have the `submited` value. I'd start modifying it, and if not solved checking wich rules is reading IE11 (nice F12!) , to find the one with the extra border width.

Comment: @miguel-svq: Alright. I was also searching if I can find any ms-* property for this border but I could not find any till now.

Comment: @DevPat: Please see similar kind of scenario here: http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/qTV3g/

Comment: Better explained: Check the difference between the answers to IE11 and chrome, the class are not the same: `ng-pristine` vs `ng-dirty` and there is no `submited` class.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This ugly appearance in IE is caused by the outline property. You can remove it with this:

```
input:required:invalid {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: And... 
textarea:required:invalid {
    outline: none;
}

Answer (score 1):

**1. Test Application for the current senario**

Here is test application I created for your scenario: [**Plunker1**](http://plnkr.co/edit/RGhMm2r0yj9uoY29dBGo?p=preview)

Below CSS class has been used to highlight the required input fields that failed validation:

```css
    .submitted input:invalid {
        border: red 1px solid; }
```

Running this in IE 10 and Chrome 32 doesn't have the desired effect. The default :invalid CSS is applied to the invalid fields. It's not the one from user defined CSS. This rules out the possiblity that IE and Chrome are behaving differently in the scenario in subject.

**2. Revelations from research on web**

Following the example [here](http://html5doctor.com/css3-pseudo-classes-and-html5-forms/), I created another test application here: **[Plunker2](http://plnkr.co/edit/PH1wGVKAqDAU1J36PeCz?p=preview)**
This works fine in both IE 10 and Chrome 32.

Essentially we are removing default form validation on submit and adding custom validation that uses user defined CSS.

*Changed HTML:*

```html
    <button formnovalidate="" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

*JavaScript*

```js
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.currentTarget.classList.add('submitted');
        });
    });
```

**Note**: You can as well use `window.onload` instead of `DOMContentLoaded` event.

Hope this helps in resolving the issue you are facing.

Comment: +1 for the efforts you took to solve my issue. I too did it without applying form validation. Before doing this way, I would try to do it by keeping default validations. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
input:required:invalid{
outline-color:red;
outline-width:thin;
}
```